# how to change a ViewController to another that has no ".xib"?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view controller that generates the ".xib" with Three20

I want a tableView Send me this ViewController has no ".xib" as you do?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    if (!self.albumController) {
        self.albumController = (AlThumbsViewController *)self; //AlThumbsViewController no have xib  //Three20 is generated automatically with
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.albumController animated:YES];
    [self.albumController release];
    self.albumController = nil;
}
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: Can you clarify? Your question is unclear...

Comment: I want to move from a "1.-ViewController" to "2.-ViewController" but the 2 does not have xib as I move?

I tried as follows:
  UINavigationController * nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: [[AlThumbsViewController alloc] init]];
[window addSubview: nav.view];
     / / Override point for customization after application launch
     [makeKeyAndVisible window]
    
But I make mistake.

Comment: #import <Three20/Three20.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

interface ALThumbsViewController : TTThumbsViewController {

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyViewController *view = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];

```
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:NO]; ---> you can use YES
```

or 
 [self.view addsubview:view.view];

and for opposite

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

[self.view romovefromsuperview];

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to transition from one view controller, to a second view controller which did not have a NIB/XIB file generated for it when you created the second view controller?

If so, you need to create a create a new XIB in xcode. Go to New File, User Interface, View. Then associate the new XIB file to the view controller by changing the Class Name in interface builder for your XIB to the same name as your view controller. Then set the view outlet in Interface Builder to the main view of the XIB. Then do initWithNibName on your view controller that does not have a XIB, and pass it the new XIB file you just created.

EDITED BASED ON COMMENT:

Step 1: Create a new file, User Interface, View. This will generate a stand alone XIB file.

Step 2: Go to your new XIB. Click File's Owner. Click Identity Inspector icon on right menu (the middle little icon). For "Class" change the name to the exact name of the view controller you want to link it to.

Step 3: Click file's owner. Click Connections Inspector icon on right menu (the right most little icon). Under Outlets, connect "view" to the main view of the XIB (just drag from the circle to the main window).

Step 4: Load your view controller like this:

```
MyViewController *view = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: YES, I want to do to create a new Xib and add it and the other did not understand you comment me you could explain better but I'd appreciate it I have this question 3 days. @Joel

Comment: Step 1.2 and 4 if I understand.
I show you the picture if I did the right thing please tell me.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/826/capturadepantalla201205k.png

Step 3 does not understand that I must do.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Receiver 'AlThumbsViewController is forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist.

Comment: The picture is correct. For step 3 click the last tab, and under "Outlets", "view" drag the circle over to the window in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [picture](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/444/capturadepantalla201205tm.png/)?

```
error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_ $ _AlThumbsViewController", Referenced from:
       objc-class-ref in SocialesAlbumViewController.o
ld: symbol (s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use-v to see invocation)
```

see [image](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/513/capturadepantalla201205vl.png/) here

Comment: Does ALThumbsViewController descend from UIViewController? It should.

Comment: You should also change the code to be self.albumController = [[AlThumbsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AlThumbsViewController" bundle:nil]; or assign the view variable to self.albumController.

Comment: Im use Three20.
ALThumbsViewController descend form TTThumbsViewController
 
#import <Three20/Three20.h>

interface ALThumbsViewController : TTThumbsViewController {

}

end

Comment: Does TTThumbsViewController descend from UIViewController?

Comment: Nop.
I'm trying to do a photo gallery, and I can do it you could give me some advice?

Comment: Size as to give a ImagenView:

My code but not work:
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:urlData];
    //imagen.image = image;
    
    //UIImage* myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fancy_picture.png"];
    float newImgHeight = image.size.height;
    
    CGRect myViewFrame = CGRectMake(80,80,80,80);
    imagen.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: myViewFrame];